# devtools::check generates an error (install options '--no-html --no-multiarch) at seemingly randomly times

Tags: r, devtools

I am creating my own package and use devtools to document and check the package. About 50% of the time that I run devtools::check() it ends with this error:

```
❯ checking whether package 'snafun' can be installed ... ERROR See below...

── Install failure ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

install options '--no-html --no-multiarch
```

However, this only happens about half the time. Sometimes it doesn't and sometimes it does. I can run devtools::check several times in a row (without making any change to the code or the session in between) and get this error on half of the runs, and on the other half not. And sometimes it seems to help if I restart the session in between an other times it makes no difference.

I have tried playing with the arguments of devtools::check, but that doesn;t seem to affect the error (which could be related to this being an "Install failure" and devtools::check doesn't have install arguments).

I am puzzled. I have the following questions:

- what does this error even mean? Is it problematic?
- what can make it occur and disappear seemingly randomly?
- what might be a direction to solve this?

ps the package is quite large, so I can't really turn this into a reprex

Comment: You should narrow down the issue.  Does it only occur when you use `devtools::check()`, or would it happen with `R CMD check` as well?  Since it's an install problem, what about `R CMD INSTALL`? More in the next comment...

Comment: There are lots of ways for computer code to be non-deterministic.  You might have used a random number generator in one of your .R files, so the code itself is random.  (You'd probably know about this, but maybe you didn't realize that the code in your source files is run at install time.)  Or maybe you have some poorly written code that refers to uninitialized variables, and it is seeing whatever value happened to be at that spot in memory; this would appear random.  One more...

Comment: Back to the first comment:  narrowing this down is essential.  Once you have the minimal process to generate the problem semi-regularly, start taking things out of your package until you have a minimal package that still generates it.  Maybe that will be small enough that you *can* post it here.  In the meantime, I'm voting to close, because we don't have anything to go on.

Comment: Than you, that makes sense. However, is there anything specific about this error? It would help to know when this specific error is triggered, so I have a direction that I can take for the narrowing down. In other words, what must be true for devtools::check to report the install options '--no-html --no-multiarch' error?

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same problem and I solved it installing the rcmdcheck package.

```
install.packages("rcmdcheck")
library(rcmdcheck)
rcmdcheck('MyPath/MyPackage')
```